# Using VBA to export each table in a worksheet onto a seperate page in a single PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I can create a macro to export each table to their own PDF but is there a way to place each table on it's own page in a single PDF?

```
Range("B2:C5").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$B$5"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
    True
Range("B2:C6").Select
```

All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around with merging PDF's a couple of years ago and put something together that would merge any PDF's I chose into 1 for me.

This is the merge part of my code, you will need to adapt it to your needs:

```
Sub MergePDFs()
Dim a As Variant, i As Long, n As Long, ni As Long, p As String
Dim AcroApp As New Acrobat.AcroApp, PartDocs() As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

MyPath = Range("G1").Text
DestFile = Range("G2").Text
MyFiles = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)), ",")

  If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then p = MyPath Else p = MyPath & "\"
  a = Split(MyFiles, ",")
  ReDim PartDocs(0 To UBound(a))

  On Error GoTo exit_
  If Len(Dir(p & DestFile)) Then Kill p & DestFile
  For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    ' Check PDF file presence
    If Dir(p & Trim(a(i))) = "" Then
      MsgBox "File not found" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
      Exit For
    End If
    ' Open PDF document
    Set PartDocs(i) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    PartDocs(i).Open p & Trim(a(i))
    If i Then
      ' Merge PDF to PartDocs(0) document
      ni = PartDocs(i).GetNumPages()
      If Not PartDocs(0).InsertPages(n - 1, PartDocs(i), 0, ni, True) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot insert pages of" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
      End If
      ' Calc the number of pages in the merged document
      n = n + ni
      ' Release the memory
      PartDocs(i).Close
      Set PartDocs(i) = Nothing
    Else
      ' Calc the number of pages in PartDocs(0) document
      n = PartDocs(0).GetNumPages()
    End If
  Next

  If i > UBound(a) Then
    ' Save the merged document to DestFile
    If Not PartDocs(0).Save(PDSaveFull, p & DestFile) Then
      MsgBox "Cannot save the resulting document" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbExclamation, "Canceled"
    End If
  End If

exit_:

  ' Inform about error/success
  If Err Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error #" & Err.Number
  ElseIf i > UBound(a) Then
    MsgBox "The resulting file is created:" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbInformation, "Done"
  End If

  ' Release the memory
  If Not PartDocs(0) Is Nothing Then PartDocs(0).Close
  Set PartDocs(0) = Nothing

  ' Quit Acrobat application
  AcroApp.Exit
  Set AcroApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

From memory I didn't write this routine in my merge tool but I can't remember where I got it so i can't credit the original coder.

Comment: I've had a play with this now and I'm adding it to my own libraries, my thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After setting  each sheet PageSetup, then you export workbook.

```
Sub test()

    Dim WB As Workbook, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim myFn As String
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    For Each Ws In Worksheets
        Ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:$B$5"
    Next Ws
    myFn = WB.Path & "\" & "test.pdf"

    WB.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, myFn
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, after a few minutes playing I remodelled my spreadsheet to place the event tables on separate worksheets and used your code... it is arguably a more robust solution now and easier to upgrade in the future.